# Arduino - How to multithread this application

Tags: arduino

I'm writing a garage door opener and monitor.

The monitor receives the door status via another Arduino over [RF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_frequency) (315 MHz). The code below works, but I feel that I shouldn't need to check the status every time I make a request to the server to open the door.  Is there a way to split the code out so that I check the door status every 20 seconds, and the opening and closing of the garage are on demand?

Here is the code:
https://github.com/dhysong/ArduinoGarageOpener/blob/master/src/GarageDoorOpener/GarageDoorOpener.ino

Comment: 2 down votes with now comment.  Does no one else think this might be a valid question?  I guess I must have offended the SO gods!

Comment: Don't you think you should ask the author of the project?

Comment: I don't understand, I am the author.  I didn't downvote my own post.

Comment: Oups, my bad, I didn't notice that! I didn't vote down your post, though...

Comment: You might be better off posting to the arduino forums (http://arduino.cc/forum/). That community is huge + very friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this post: http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,5686.0.html

I was able to add a mult-threading like capability to my app.  Source code has been updated to reflect the change.

Here's the pertinent piece:

```
boolean cycleCheck(unsigned long *lastMillis, unsigned int cycle) 
{
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if(currentMillis - *lastMillis >= cycle)
{
  *lastMillis = currentMillis;
  return true;
 }
else
  return false;
}
```

Here's the github code for anyone that might benefit:  https://github.com/dhysong/ArduinoGarageOpener/blob/master/src/GarageDoorOpener/GarageDoorOpener.ino

Comment: I just looked at: http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/Interrupts, and I'm not clear on how this would solve my problem.  Could you please elaborate or provide some example source code?  thanks, Drew

Comment: Take a look at a blog post I wrote some time ago: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/08/26/digital-clock-on-arduino-uno-with-nokia-lcd-display/ In the project I use interrupts to get correct timing for my clock. The source is on github - you can find the link in the post.

Comment: Thanks Pawel.  I'll take a look when I get a chance (this is all hobby) and see if I can't improve on this thread.

Comment: So did you end up using interrupts drew?